# Resuming a recursive function in C (gcc)?

Tags: c, gcc, recursion

I use gcc (gnu99) under linux. 
Assume I have a simple function that computes (say, prints)  some values.
To fix ideas without resorting to factorial, let me propose this little toy function:

```
void rec(int val, int nd)
{
   val *= 10; nd++;
   for (int u=0; u<=9; u++, val++)
       if (val && 0==(val%(nd*nd)))
       {
         printf("%d\n",val);
         rec(val,nd);
       }
}
```

which called as rec(0,0), will print the 86 positive numbers with the property that every their prefix of length k is divisible by k^2 (largest is 6480005).

Q: is there a standard way to turn it into a routine which can be called repeatedly and each time returns a new value until it signals in some way that there are no more values ?

In practice, I need a way to call rec(), getting back a value, and then be able to resume execution from where it was, to get next value and so on.

I thought about using a combination of setjmp(), longjmp(), setcontext() and the like, but the examples on these topics confused me a little.
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a [*coroutine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutines#Implementations_for_C).

Comment: workaround: pass a callback function.

Comment: @Oli Although in this case, a generator would suffice. They are usually much easier to implement in languages that do not have support for coroutines – but require much more math-y transformation of the algorithm to run well.

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to `setjmp()` and its likes, I would think of two possibilities to achieve your objective.

### Define a structure and functions that operate on it

You can define a structure that contains the state you are interested in:

```
struct S {
  int *  numbers;
  size_t length;
  size_t current;
}
```

and a set of functions that operate on it:

```
// Basically your rec(val,nd) function
int initialize(int val, int nd, S* s);
// Get the next value
int getNextValue(const S* s);
...
// Free memory
void Sfree(S* s);
```

### Embed a state into your own function

In this case you embed a persistent state (using some `static` variable) directly into your function `rec()`. Being persistent this state will be preserved across different calls to the function, and permit you to keep track of how many times the function was called and of any other information you may need. Beware that this solution requires a particular care if used inside multi-threaded environments.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ this is done via a class that holds a the `state` (variables).

In C, the preferred method of operation is to pass this `state` or `context` to the function.

Do **not** use a global state as later on you'll find that it causes too many issues.

Example:

```
int foo(struct fooContext* c, int arg1, int arg2) {
}
```